# CloudInit, Kernel Upgrades & DKMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, cloud, cloud-init

I'm using cloud-init to configure my EC2 instances at launch time, currently just on CentOS 7. I need to upgrade to the latest kernel, etc so first I have:

```
package_upgrade: true
```

Then I add a bunch of repos and install some packages with yum that ultimately compile some kernel modules with DKMS (Nvidia drivers)

Finally I reboot the system with:

```
power_state:
    mode:               reboot
    timeout:            30
```

This all works great! However, when the system comes back up, DKMS reports that the nvidia driver is "added" but not installed and the Nvidia driver doesn't work. If I `yum reinstall nvidia-kmod` everything works. So obviously what's happening is the kernel module is being compiled and installed for the previous kernel and not the new kernel.

So what is the suggested way to solve this? Is there a way to reboot after the package_upgrade but before any of the other steps? Is there a way to force nvidia-kmod to compile for the new kernel and not the current kernel? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only real option is to create a cloud-init per-boot script that runs `dkms-autoinstall`. This attempts to compile any "added" kernel module that aren't yet installed on every boot.